# Totally uni modular matrix with binary variable

Tags: matlab

please can you help me in solving this problem

I have totally uni-modular matrix A multiplied by set of Binary variables X.

it means that A*X<=B

how to solve this problem in polynomial time .. I am interested in finding just one feasible solution.

For example I have:

```
A= [ 1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0 ;
     0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0 ;
     0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1 ;
     1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0 ;
     0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1 ;
    -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0 ;
     0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0  0 ;
     0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0 ;
     0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 ];

B= [ 2 ; 2; 2; 3; 2;-3;-3;-2;-2];
```

Comment: A= [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ;
    1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ;
    -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1;
    ];
B=[2;2;2;3;2;-3;-3;-2;-2];

Comment: you can edit your question, I did that for you. What do you mean whit polynomial time? What about `A\B = X`?

Comment: thank you for editing the question .. it is not possible to solve it in this way because inverse of A is undefined , the determination of A is zero

Comment: but it gives a solution, isn't it a feasable one?

Comment: how it is feasible solution ? what is the values of X in this case

Comment: >> A\B
ans =
   -0.0000
         0
    2.0000
    1.0000
   -0.0000
   -1.0000
    2.0000
    1.0000

Comment: okay , but this is not a solution , the X values should be just 0 or 1 , I mean that maybe there is no solution for equality , but there is feasible solution for inequality

Comment: There exist multiple solutions, symbolic toolbox available?

Comment: have a look at the additional parameters of `lsqlin` then; [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html)

Answer (score 0):

This easily solved with [`bintprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/bintprog.html) (binary integer programming) from the Optimization toolbox:

```
x = bintprog(ones(size(A,2),1),A,b)
```

which returns

```
x =

      0
      1
      1
      1
      0
      0
      1
      1
```

You can easily confirm that `A*x` yields `b`. Of course it's not guaranteed that this is the only solution. For more on the `bintprog` algorithm and options for tuning, see [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/binary-integer-programming-algorithms.html#f786287). According to [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Exact_algorithms), the branch-and-bound method on which `bintprog` is based can have polynomial time complexity.

Additionally, as @thewaywewalk points out, [`lsqlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) can also be leveraged:

```
x = lsqlin(A,b,A,b,[],[],zeros(size(A,2),1),ones(size(A,2),1))
```